# How to use foreign key with composite keys in android room inside an entity, which only saves one key and the other one is given implicitly

Tags: foreign-keys, android-room, composite-key

Let's say I have a Category Entity, of which only two types exist (category A and category B). The primary key is a composite key consisting of the category name and a boolean stating, if the category belongs to category A (B otherwise).

An Item can belong to these two category types at the same time. In my Item Entity, I therefore have two foreign keys (categoryAName and categoryBName), both of which may be null, if they don't belong to any category. Is there a way to map the foreign key with its two composite keys inside the Item Entity, if the category type is only given implicitly?

My code looks as follows:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "category_table", primaryKeys = ["name", "isCategoryA"])
data class CategoryEntity(val name: String, val isCategoryA: Boolean)


@Entity(
    tableName = "item_table",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = CategoryEntity::class,
        parentColumns = ["name", "isCategoryA"],
        childColumns = ["categoryAName", "???"], // how would one set the colum, if we don't want to save the value, when it's known implicitly?
        onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL,
        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    ), ForeignKey(
        entity = CategoryEntity::class,
        parentColumns = ["name", "isCategoryA"],
        childColumns = ["categoryBName", "???"], // isCategoryA would always be false
        onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL,
        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class ItemEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val name: String,
    var categoryAName: String?,
    var categoryBName: String?
)
```

Is there a way to achieve this, without adding two additional columns, which just contain redundant information? Or is there a better way to implement this in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is there a better way to implement this in general?

I believe the better way is to incorporate a many-many relationship and thus a table (Entity) that facilitates this. Although I do find the explanation you provide difficult to understand in that you are saying that Categories belong to a Category.

That is you either have 2 or 4 categories (the example assumes 4 each either belong to itself or the other).

An Item would appear to be able to have 1,2, 3 or 4 Categories.

As such you could have :-

- an Entity for the Categories
- an Entity for the Items
- and an Entity for the mapping of an Item to the 4 (or 2) Categories that it may have.

So :-

**CategoryEntity** could be :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "category_table",
    indices = [
        Index(
            value = ["name","isCategoryA"],
            unique = true
        )
    ])
data class CategoryEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val categoryId: Long,
    val name: String,
    val isCategoryA: Boolean
    )
```

- the addition of an id column that uniquely identifies the category.

**ItemEntity** could be :-

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "item_table"
)
data class ItemEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val name: String
)
```

- greatly simplified

**ItemCategoryMap**

```
@Entity(
        primaryKeys = ["categoryId","itemName"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = CategoryEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["categoryId"],
            childColumns = ["categoryId"]
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = ItemEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["name"],
            childColumns = ["itemName"]
        )
    ]
)
data class ItemCategoryMap(
    val categoryId: Long, val itemName: String
)
```

A POJO that combines the Item with the respective categories as per the map table **ItemWithCategories** :-

```
data class ItemWithCategories(
    @Embedded
    val item: ItemEntity,
    @Relation(
        entity = CategoryEntity::class,
        entityColumn = "categoryId",
        parentColumn = "name",
        associateBy = Junction(
            ItemCategoryMap::class,
            parentColumn = "itemName",
            entityColumn = "categoryId")
    )
    val categories: List<CategoryEntity>
)
```

A Dao **AllDao** :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(categoryEntity: CategoryEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(itemEntity: ItemEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(itemCategoryMap: ItemCategoryMap): Long
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table")
    fun getAllItemsWithCategories(): List<ItemWithCategories>
    @Query("SELECT name FROM ITEM_TABLE WHERE rowid=:rowid")
    fun getItemNameByRowid(rowid: Long): String
}
```

an @Database **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = [CategoryEntity::class, ItemEntity::class, ItemCategoryMap::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
         public fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
             if (instance == null) {
                 instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"mydb")
                     .allowMainThreadQueries()
                     .build()
             }
             return instance as TheDatabase
         }
    }
}
```

- note for demo run on main thread

An finally an Activity that puts it all together and outputs the extracted Items with the Categories (0-4) :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()

        val catATrueID =dao.insert(CategoryEntity(0,"CatA",true))
        val catAFalseId = dao.insert(CategoryEntity(0,"CatA",false))
        val catBTrueId = dao.insert(CategoryEntity(0,"CatB",true))
        val catBFalseId = dao.insert(CategoryEntity(0,"CatB",false))
        val catOoops = dao.insert(CategoryEntity(0,"CatB",false))

        val item1name = dao.getItemNameByRowid(dao.insert(ItemEntity("Item1")))
        dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catATrueID,item1name))
        dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catAFalseId,item1name))
        dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catBTrueId,item1name))
        dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catBFalseId,item1name))

        val item2name = dao.getItemNameByRowid(dao.insert(ItemEntity("Item2")))
        dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catBFalseId,item2name))
        dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catATrueID,item2name))

        val item3name = dao.getItemNameByRowid(dao.insert(ItemEntity("Item3")))
        dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catBTrueId,item3name))

        val item4name = dao.getItemNameByRowid(dao.insert(ItemEntity("item4")))

        for(iwc: ItemWithCategories in dao.getAllItemsWithCategories()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO",
                "Item is ${iwc.item.name} has ${iwc.categories.size} categories." )
            for (c: CategoryEntity in iwc.categories) {
                Log.d("DBINFO","Category is ${c.name} ID is ${c.categoryId} IsCategoryA is ${c.isCategoryA}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result** (only designed to be run once for the demo) :-

```
2021-06-24 14:56:02.614 D/DBINFO: Item is Item1 has 4 categories.
2021-06-24 14:56:02.614 D/DBINFO: Category is CatA ID is 1 IsCategoryA is true
2021-06-24 14:56:02.614 D/DBINFO: Category is CatA ID is 2 IsCategoryA is false
2021-06-24 14:56:02.615 D/DBINFO: Category is CatB ID is 3 IsCategoryA is true
2021-06-24 14:56:02.615 D/DBINFO: Category is CatB ID is 4 IsCategoryA is false
2021-06-24 14:56:02.615 D/DBINFO: Item is Item2 has 2 categories.
2021-06-24 14:56:02.615 D/DBINFO: Category is CatB ID is 4 IsCategoryA is false
2021-06-24 14:56:02.615 D/DBINFO: Category is CatA ID is 1 IsCategoryA is true
2021-06-24 14:56:02.615 D/DBINFO: Item is Item3 has 1 categories.
2021-06-24 14:56:02.615 D/DBINFO: Category is CatB ID is 3 IsCategoryA is true
2021-06-24 14:56:02.615 D/DBINFO: Item is item4 has 0 categories.
```

**Addtional**

Regarding

> As shown with my code example, an item may belong to only ONE category for EACH type. Therefore, the item may only belong to 2 categories at most. Moreover, two categories may have the same name, but ONLY, if they belong to a different type (that's why there is a composite key). There should be no two categories with the same name, having the same type.

Then you can limit to a unique category name by having a unique index on the category name item name combination. As such the **ItemCategoryMap** can be amended to be :-

```
@Entity(
        primaryKeys = ["categoryId","itemName"],
    indices = [Index("itemName","categoryName",unique = true)] /* ADDED FOR ADDITIONAL */,
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = CategoryEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["categoryId"],
            childColumns = ["categoryId"]
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = ItemEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["name"],
            childColumns = ["itemName"]
        )
    ]
)
data class ItemCategoryMap(
    val categoryId: Long , val categoryName: String /* ADDED FOR ADDITIONAL */, val itemName: String
)
```

As the category name is now required then the category name is required as an index has to be specific to a single table. As such when inserting the categoryName is required.

So amending the invoking (**MainActivity**) to be changed to use (rest of the code is as it was) :-

```
    val item1name = dao.getItemNameByRowid(dao.insert(ItemEntity("Item1")))
    dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catATrueID,"CatA",item1name))
    dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catAFalseId,"CatA",item1name))
    dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catBTrueId,"CatB",item1name))
    dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catBFalseId,"CatB",item1name))

    val item2name = dao.getItemNameByRowid(dao.insert(ItemEntity("Item2")))
    dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catBFalseId,"CatB",item2name))
    dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catATrueID,"CatA",item2name))

    val item3name = dao.getItemNameByRowid(dao.insert(ItemEntity("Item3")))
    dao.insert(ItemCategoryMap(catBTrueId,"CatB",item3name))

    val item4name = dao.getItemNameByRowid(dao.insert(ItemEntity("item4")))
```

The **Result** is now :-

```
2021-06-25 10:01:22.671 D/DBINFO: Item is Item1 has 2 categories.
2021-06-25 10:01:22.671 D/DBINFO: Category is CatA ID is 1 IsCategoryA is true
2021-06-25 10:01:22.671 D/DBINFO: Category is CatB ID is 3 IsCategoryA is true
2021-06-25 10:01:22.671 D/DBINFO: Item is Item2 has 2 categories.
2021-06-25 10:01:22.672 D/DBINFO: Category is CatA ID is 1 IsCategoryA is true
2021-06-25 10:01:22.672 D/DBINFO: Category is CatB ID is 4 IsCategoryA is false
2021-06-25 10:01:22.672 D/DBINFO: Item is Item3 has 1 categories.
2021-06-25 10:01:22.672 D/DBINFO: Category is CatB ID is 3 IsCategoryA is true
2021-06-25 10:01:22.672 D/DBINFO: Item is item4 has 0 categories.
```

That is:-

- The attempt to insert a duplicate CatB false using `val catOoops = dao.insert(CategoryEntity(0,"CatB",false))` is IGNORED so the duplicate is added (i.e. just the 4 Category rows) as per :-
- [image]
- Item1 has only the first CatA (i.e. CatA true, the CatA false) was IGNORED. Likewise for CatB.
- Item2 has both as no rules were broken when inserting both.
- Item3 has just the one no rules were broken.
- Item has none.

If you wanted to get Categories with the associated Items then you could have **CategoryWithItems** :-

```
data class CategoryWithItems (
    @Embedded
    val category: CategoryEntity,
    @Relation(
        entity = ItemEntity::class,
        entityColumn = "name",
        parentColumn = "categoryId",
        associateBy = Junction(
            ItemCategoryMap::class,
            parentColumn = "categoryId",
            entityColumn = "itemName")
    )
    val items: List<ItemEntity>
)
```

And a dao such as :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM category_table")
fun getAllCategoriesWithItems(): List<CategoryWithItems>
```

Using (with the data loaded above) :-

```
    for(cwi: CategoryWithItems in dao.getAllCategoriesWithItems()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO", "Category is ${cwi.category.name} isCategoryA is ${cwi.category.isCategoryA} id is ${cwi.category.categoryId}, it has ${cwi.items.size} associated Items")
        for(i: ItemEntity in cwi.items) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","\tItem is ${i.name}")
        }
    }
```

The result would be :-

```
2021-06-25 10:53:24.852 D/DBINFO: Category is CatA isCategoryA is true id is 1, it has 2 associated Items
2021-06-25 10:53:24.852 D/DBINFO:   Item is Item1
2021-06-25 10:53:24.852 D/DBINFO:   Item is Item2
2021-06-25 10:53:24.852 D/DBINFO: Category is CatA isCategoryA is false id is 2, it has 0 associated Items
2021-06-25 10:53:24.853 D/DBINFO: Category is CatB isCategoryA is true id is 3, it has 2 associated Items
2021-06-25 10:53:24.853 D/DBINFO:   Item is Item1
2021-06-25 10:53:24.853 D/DBINFO:   Item is Item3
2021-06-25 10:53:24.853 D/DBINFO: Category is CatB isCategoryA is false id is 4, it has 1 associated Items
2021-06-25 10:53:24.853 D/DBINFO:   Item is Item2
```

of course WHERE clauses could be utilised.

**NOTE/WARNING** the use in the code of

```
val item1name = dao.getItemNameByRowid(dao.insert(ItemEntity("Item1")))
```

(etc i.e. getting the name of the inserted item via the rowid will result in a failure if rerun, it's use is just intended to simplify the demo code).

The above solution also caters for more that just the 2 category names, that is there is no limit to the category names (other than storage limitations).

Comment: Thank you for your input so far. Sorry if my question was not clear enough. As shown with my code example, an item may belong to only ONE category for EACH type. Therefore, the item may only belong to 2 categories at most. Moreover, two categories may have the same name, but ONLY, if they belong to a different type (that's why there is a composite key). There should be no two categories with the same name, having the same type.

Comment: @Mexes updated the answer basically adding an index to enforce the mapping so that the rule  *There should be no two categories with the same name, having the same type.* is followed.